# Express.js 4 - Router Partition Example Code Fails

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, directory

**EDIT**
For those of you just finding this, the documentation for Express has an error in this example. You need to use the `next();` statement in the part:

```
people.use(function(req, res, next) {
    next();//Added to make example work
});
```

**Original Post**

If you look at the [Express 4.0 documentation](https://github.com/visionmedia/express/wiki/New-features-in-4.x) under "Routes", a method is suggested for using router to split up the application. I tried to make an example application.

**app.js**

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var port = process.env.PORT || 8080;

app.route('/').get(function(req, res, next) {
    res.send('Hello World');
});

//Try to use modular routes ...
app.use('/people', require('./routes/people').people);

//Start up server
app.listen(port);
console.log('Magic happens on port ' + port);
```

**people.js**

```
var express = require('express'); //<- Included because it throws an error otherwise
var people = express.Router();

people.use(function(req, res, next) {
});

people.get('/', function(req, res, next) {
});

module.exports.people = people;
```

**Directory Structure**

```
/
app.js
/routes
    people.js
```

When I run the project and navigate to 'localhost:8080', I get the expected 'Hello World' response. However, when I go to 'localhost:8080/people', the browser just sits and spins. Since this is example code from the project itself, I am surprised this does not work. Any thoughts?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. `people.use` needs to call the `next` function so the next middleware/route in the chain is called
2. The connection will stay alive until data is sent, so `people.get('/', ...)` needs to send something back to the client

The following `people.js` should provide the desired results:

```
var express = require('express');
var people = express.Router();

people.use(function(req, res, next) {
  next();
});

people.get('/', function(req, res, next) {
  res.send('people!');
});

module.exports.people = people;
```

Comment: Thanks for the pointer Tim. Just to clarify my understanding, the order of the routes called depends on their **source** order, correct? I am planning on making this architecture the backbone of my new application. Is there any reason not to do so?

Comment: @DiodeDan:  *the order of the routes called depends on their source order, correct* That is correct.

Answer (score -3):

because you just set route`/`,don't set route `/people` in `people.js` you should write:

`people.get('/people', function(req, res, next) {
});`